# Ubuntu 12.04 boots to blank screen without backlight after upgrade on ASUS A72J

Tags: 12.04, boot, ati, asus, backlight

I had a working version of Ubuntu 12.04 in dual boot with Windows 7 on my ASUS A72J. However, after installing the last ~350 upgrades (I had not used Ubuntu in a long time) using the normal updating program of Ubuntu, my laptop now boots to a blank screen without backlight. I think the issue might be with my video card (ATI 5470M 1GB) drivers, but I have no idea how to solve it. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/363255/lubuntu-13-10-amd-ati-radeon-laptop-screen-is-black-after-upgrade-from-13-04 there are many answers on this forum about similar problem

Comment: I will take a look at the suggestion in /363255/, thank you!

Comment: I have been trying to fix this using that suggestion. When trying to install xserver-xorg-video-ati, I got the error that two dependencies were not installed. When I tried to install these, I got the error "E: unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or run with --fix-missing"; the first returns "W: some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead" , the second gave "unable to correct missing packages." Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: that workout should've worked perfectly, did you do that in tty terminal? playing with graphics better with display manager off login to tty Ctrl+Alt+F1 then do removal and purging as suggested after that you can get an update run `sudo apt-get update` check for broken `sudo apt-get -f install` and also `sudo apt-get autoremove` then do the installing steps.

Comment: read also documentations on ATI/Radeon https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: I have been working on a solution; I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04. After install, the system boots while giving an error about the drivers. It loads anyway, and reboots do not give a problem also. However, I wanted to update my drivers anyway, so I first checked for frglx drivers, but there were none. Then I used sudo apt-get install to install the latest frglx version. It seemed that I had the latest drivers, but it booted to a black screen. In the root shell prompt, I still had the problem that I did not have internet access to use sudo apt-get update. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it and this http://askubuntu.com/questions/428878/bad-quality-and-playback-issues-when-playing-video-with-vlc/428888?noredirect=1#comment556546_428888

Comment: I did a fresh install again, and this time I tried your first suggestion again, but now I had an internet connection, so I fixed my drivers, and Ubuntu boots normally again. Thanks a lot!